# Windows 7 workstation network issue

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, domain

I have a client that has 20+ computers on a domain.  All the computers can see each other as well as the servers except one.

I have checked these:

- Remote login
- Windows firewall is turned off
- there is no antivirus
- I have rebooted the workstation
- have tried it in safe mode
- and I have checked the services

What am I missing?

Comment: Check your DNS settings. Have you tried removing the client from the domain and re-add it?

Comment: I forgot to add that this computer can see all the other computers and servers

Comment: Give me just a minute and I will try the domain removal and add again

Comment: Okay I just removed it from the domain then rebooted and then re-added it to the domain then rebooted again. However, it is still doing the same thing. Any other ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Could you please try to clarify your question a little?  For instance, this one machine that’s misbehaving –– can it see _any_ of the other computers?  And I’m not sure how to interpret your comment (“… this computer can see all the other computers …”).

Comment: The DNS is set automatically. It is like this on all the workstations.

Comment: Yes it can see all the other computers on the network but none of the other computers can see it.  It is the only one that is doing this and it just so happens to be the one the head person wants to see...go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Check the IP scheme is in line with the rest.  10.0.0.2 can't necessarily talk to 192.168.1.2.

Also, check that the machine is looking to the correct DNS server and that its search domains (control panel > network adapters > properties > ip > advanced)

Lastly, check that there are no manual entries in the computers hosts file which could be forcing it to resolve badly.

One of these should help you along your way or at least rule out a few more things.